# How to add X-FRAME-OPTIONS to some pages in Spring Security headers (Spring version 4.2.0)?

Tags: spring-security

I have enabled Spring Security headers. By default `X-FRAME-OPTIONS` is `DENY`. But for some responses I should enable `X-FRAME-OPTIONS` as `SAMEORIGIN`. I have tried adding request matcher. But it adding both as `X-Frame-Options` (`DENY`, `SAMEORIGIN`). How to avoid default one (`DENY`) for request matcher?

My code is like this:

```xml
<security:headers disabled="false">
    <security:header ref="xFrameOptionsHeaderWriter"/>
     <security:content-security-policy policy-directives="script-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'" />
     <security:cache-control disabled="true"/>
</security:headers>


<bean id="xFrameOptionsHeaderWriter" class="org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.DelegatingRequestMatcherHeaderWriter">

    <constructor-arg> 
         <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.NegatedRequestMatcher">
             <constructor-arg>
                 <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher">
                     <constructor-arg>
                         <list>
                             <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher">
                                 <constructor-arg value="/**/flows/javax.faces.resource/dynamiccontent.properties/**" /> 
                             </bean>                          
                         </list>
                     </constructor-arg>
                </bean>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>

    <constructor-arg>
        <bean  class="org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.frameoptions.XFrameOptionsHeaderWriter">
            <constructor-arg value="SAMEORIGIN"/>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 2):

Spring Security's `header` element **adds** a new HTTP header, but doesn't replace a HTTP header, see [Spring Security Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#nsa-header):

> **41.1.16 <header>**
>
> Add additional headers to the response, both the name and value need to be specified.

You have to disable the frame options, see [Spring Security Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#nsa-frame-options):

> **41.1.13 <frame-options>**
>
> When enabled adds the X-Frame-Options header to the response, this allows newer browsers to do some security checks and prevent clickjacking attacks.

Your modified Spring Security headers configuration:

```xml
<security:headers disabled="false">
    <security:frame-options disabled="true"/>
    <security:header ref="xFrameOptionsHeaderWriter"/>
    <security:content-security-policy policy-directives="script-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'" />
    <security:cache-control disabled="true"/>
</security:headers>
```